# Trouble passing the name of a property as a value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set a badge color without having to import the `palette` with my colors into another file.

I have my `routes.js` that has the following for a nav item:

```
{
    name: "Notifications",
    icon: <Icon fontSize="small">email</Icon>,
    notifications: notificationsNumber,
    badgeColor: "ywpYellow.main",
}
```

Now. `ywpYellow` is defined in `colors.js` like so:

```
const colors = {
    ywpYellow: {
        main: "#FEB913",
        focus: "#FEB913",
    },
```

Now I want to take `badgeColor` and have it display `ywpYellow`.

If I do this, it works, because `ywpYellow` is defined in palette from an import on `colors.js`

```
function SidenavCollapse({ icon, name, notifications, badgeColor, ...rest }) {
   const badgeStyle = ({palette: {ywpRed, ywpWhite, ywpYellow, ywpBlue}}) => ({
      background: ywpYellow.main,  // THIS WORKS BECAUSE IT'S A DEFINED OBJECT
   });
```

What would be the correct way of this pseudocode

```
background: badgeColor,
```

when `badgeColor` is a string containing the nomenclature of the object (`ywpYellow.main`) I am trying to call?

I have tried `palette[badgeColor]`

I have tried setting badgeColor as an object: `badgeColor: ['ywpYellow', 'main'],` and just calling it `background: badgeColor`

I have also tried the following (both ways):

```
const badgeStyle = ({palette: colors}) => ({
   background: colors[badgeColor].main,
   // background: colors[badgeColor],
```

to no avail.

Comment: the stuff you tried makes me think you didn't read my answer very carefully... Why don't you play around with the stackblitz I linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your deconstruction to just:

```
const badgeStyle = ({palette}) => {...}
```

Which should be equivalent to:

```js
const palette = {
    ywpYellow: {
        main: "#FEB913",
        focus: "#FEB913",
    }
}
```

If the property was just one level deep the syntax would be like this:

```js
const badgeColor = 'main';
const backgroundColor = palette.ywpYellow[badgeColor];
```

Because the path is nested it's a bit more complicated. You should use an array of property names, or just two separate ones.

```js
const badgeColor = ['ywpYellow', 'main'];
const backgroundColor = palette[badgeColor[0]][badgeColor[1]];
```

If there is a variable amount of property names you can iterate through them.

```js
const badgeColor = ['ywpYellow', 'main'];
let backgroundColor = palette;
for (const propName of badgeColor) {
  backgroundColor = backgroundColor[propName];
}
```

If you want to pass in the dot notation, then you can just split the string on the dot.

```js
const badgeColor = 'ywpYellow.main';
const propNames = badgeColor.split('.');
let backgroundColor = palette;
for (const propName of propNames) {
  backgroundColor = backgroundColor[propName];
}
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rdbmmu?file=index.ts

---

Here's what your final result could look like:

```js
function SidenavCollapse({ icon, name, notifications, badgeColor, ...rest }) {
  const badgeStyle = ({ palette }) => {
    const propNames = badgeColor.split('.');
    let backgroundColor = palette;
    for (const propName of propNames) {
      backgroundColor = backgroundColor[propName];
    }
    return { background: backgroundColor };
  };
}
```

Comment: If you look at my example however .. `colors` is broken down into `palette` and the individual color objects are defined there ..  I cannot access `colors` within the scope of the function.

Comment: Change your deconstruction to: `{palette: colors}`? Or just use the original `palette` name instead? `palette` is the `colors` object you showed isn't it?

Comment: @Zak edited to be more clear

Comment: OK after reading more carefully I got it ..  Thank you ..  I changed the deconstrution to `const badgeStyle = ({palette}) => ({  background: palette[badgeColor]['main'],` after changing badge to JUST `ywpYellow`